# how to take handle of a window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open an application in my window. my code is working fine in windows form but in wpf it doesn't work. here is the code with description

```
 private Process pDocked;
    private IntPtr hWndOriginalParent;
    private IntPtr hWndDocked;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);




    private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Change the docked windows size to match its parent's size. 
        MoveWindow(hWndDocked, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);
    }


    private void dockIt(string utility)
    {
        if (hWndDocked != IntPtr.Zero) //don't do anything if there's already a window docked.
            return;
        //hWndParent = IntPtr.Zero;

        pDocked = Process.Start(utility);
        while (hWndDocked == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            pDocked.WaitForInputIdle(1000); //wait for the window to be ready for input;
            pDocked.Refresh();              //update process info
            if (pDocked.HasExited)
            {
                return; //abort if the process finished before we got a handle.
            }
            hWndDocked = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;  //cache the window handle
        }
        //Windows API call to change the parent of the target window.
        //It returns the hWnd of the window's parent prior to this call.
        hWndOriginalParent = SetParent(hWndDocked, panel1.Handle);

        //Wire up the event to keep the window sized to match the control
        panel1.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(panel1_Resize);
        //Perform an initial call to set the size.
        panel1_Resize(new Object(), new EventArgs());
    }
```

And on the button click i am passing the notepad in dockit but it doesn't work,
how do i make it work in wpf, any panel(dockpanel, stackpanel) but they doesn't support resizing the window

Comment: after using windows forms integration it open utility but that is not visible

Comment: and i want to open it in a tabitem

Comment: Can you expand this a bit? Explain your intent, what you expect to happen and what you actually observe (in both win forms and wpf).

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
                new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

 dockIt("notepad");
  host.Child = panel1;
this.grid1.Children.Add(host);

Comment: ok this is the segment of code i am using to open it in wpf grid

Comment: but i want to call dockit() in a tabcontrol in wpf , and that is not working

Comment: to get the handle you can use new WindowInteropHelper(YOUR_WINDOW).Handle
but can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually i want to open  notepad in tabcontrol in wpf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can host the notepad in your WPF window like this: add a WindowsFormsHost to your window, set System.Windows.Forms.Panel as it's child and use panel's handle.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    private Process pDocked;
    private IntPtr hWndOriginalParent;
    private IntPtr hWndDocked;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Panel pannel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pannel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        host.Child = pannel;
        dockIt("notepad.exe");
    }

    private void dockIt(string utility)
    {
        if (hWndDocked != IntPtr.Zero) //don't do anything if there's already a window docked.
            return;

        pDocked = Process.Start(utility);
        while (hWndDocked == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            pDocked.WaitForInputIdle(1000); //wait for the window to be ready for input;
            pDocked.Refresh();              //update process info
            if (pDocked.HasExited)
            {
                return; //abort if the process finished before we got a handle.
            }
            hWndDocked = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;  //cache the window handle
        }
        //Windows API call to change the parent of the target window.
        //It returns the hWnd of the window's parent prior to this call.
        hWndOriginalParent = SetParent(hWndDocked, pannel.Handle);

        //Wire up the event to keep the window sized to match the control
        SizeChanged += window_SizeChanged;
        //Perform an initial call to set the size.
        AlignToPannel();
    }

    private void AlignToPannel()
    {
        MoveWindow(hWndDocked, 0, 0, pannel.Width, pannel.Height, true);
    }

    void window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AlignToPannel();
    }
}
```

window xaml:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Notepad">
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

But once you will put your WindowsFormsHost in a tab there will be plenty of WinForms/WPF integration issues.
The best source of knowledge on this topic I've found in this article ["Mitigating Airspace Issues In WPF Applications"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications.aspx). Good luck.

Comment: this is working fine but already explain that can it be possible for tab control or you can can i open it as a tabitem